# Sorting of html-table with data from sql-query by clicking on field-name

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting, html-table

I have an sql-database, where data can be read out by an html-form. The data are shown in an html-table, this works fine! However, I would like to make the table sortable, which means, that by clicking on the respective field-name the data should be sorted according to this field (ascending/descending). I have tried different javaScript-solutions including tablesorter.com that work well in "normal" tables, however, not in this table that is built dynamically with data from a database. Here is my code that creates the table (code without specific link to JavaScript-files):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM fruitdatabase WHERE (" . implode(", ",   
 $spalten) . ") = (" . implode(", ", $werte) . ")";

 $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Invalid query"); //Running the   
 query and storing it in result
 $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);  // gets number of rows in result   
 table
 $numcols = mysqli_num_fields($result);   // gets number of columns in  
 result table
 $field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result); // gets the column names from the 
 result table
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);



 if ($numrows > 0) {

 echo "<table id=myTable class=tablesorter>";



 echo "<thead><tr>";

 echo "<th>" . 'Nr' . "</th>";


 for($x=0;$x<$numcols;$x++){

 echo "<th>" . $field[$x]->name . "</th>";

 }
 echo "</tr></thead>";
 echo "<tbody><tr>";
 $nr = 1;

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<td>" . $nr . "</td>";
  for ($k=0; $k<$numcols; $k++) {    //  goes around until there are no    
 columns left
    echo "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>"; //Prints the data
   }

 $nr = $nr + 1;
 echo "</tr></tbody>";

 }

 echo "</table>";

 }
 }

 mysqli_close($db);
 ?>
```

One of the javaScript-files I tried:

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";
    var tableSort = function (tab) {
                    var titel = tab.getElementsByTagName("thead")     
 [0].getElementsByTagName("tr")[
                            0].getElementsByTagName("th");
                    var tbdy = tab.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                    var tz = tbdy.rows;
                    var nzeilen = tz.length;
                    if (nzeilen == 0) return;
                    var nspalten = tz[0].cells.length;
                    var arr = new Array(nzeilen);
                    var sortiert = -1;
                    var sorttype = new Array(nspalten);
                    var sortbuttonStyle = document.createElement   
 ('style'); // Stylesheet für Button im TH
                    sortbuttonStyle.innerText =
                            '.sortbutton { width:100%; height:100%; border: 
 none; background-color: transparent; font: inherit; color: inherit; text-
 align: inherit; padding: 0; cursor: pointer; } .sortbutton::-moz-focus-
 inner { margin: -1px; border-width: 1px; padding: 0; }';
                    document.head.appendChild(sortbuttonStyle);
                    var initTableHead = function (sp) { // Kopfzeile 
 vorbereiten
                            var b = document.createElement("button");
                            b.type = "button";
                            b.className = "sortbutton";
                            b.innerHTML = titel[sp].innerHTML;
                            b.addEventListener("click", function () {
                                    tsort(sp);
                            }, false);
                            titel[sp].innerHTML = "";
                            titel[sp].appendChild(b);
                    }
                    var getData = function (ele, s) {
                                    var val = ele.innerHTML;
                                    if (!isNaN(val) && val.search(/[0-9]/) !
 = -1) return val;
                                    var n = val.replace(",", ".");
                                    if (!isNaN(n) && n.search(/[0-9]/) != 
 -1) return n;
                                    sorttype[s] = "s"; // String
                                    return val;
                            } // getData
                    var vglFkt_s = function (a, b) {
                                    var as = a[sortiert],
                                            bs = b[sortiert];
                                    if (as > bs) return 1;
                                    else return -1;
                            } // vglFkt_s
                    var vglFkt_n = function (a, b) {
                                    return parseFloat(a[sortiert]) -     
 parseFloat(b[sortiert]);
                            } // vglFkt_n
                    var tsort = function (sp) {
                                    if (sp == sortiert) arr.reverse(); // 
 Tabelle ist schon nach dieser Spalte sortiert, also nur Reihenfolge 
 umdrehen
                                    else { // Sortieren
                                            sortiert = sp;
                                            if (sorttype[sp] == "n")    
 arr.sort(vglFkt_n);
                                            else arr.sort(vglFkt_s);
                                    }
                                    for (var z = 0; z < nzeilen; z++) 
 tbdy.appendChild(arr[z][nspalten]); // Sortierte Daten zurückschreiben
                            } // tsort
                            // Kopfzeile vorbereiten
                    for (var i = 0; i < titel.length; i++) initTableHead(i);
                    // Array mit Info, wie Spalte zu sortieren ist, 
 vorbelegen
                    for (var s = 0; s < nspalten; s++) sorttype[s] = "n";
                    // Tabelleninhalt in ein Array kopieren
                    for (var z = 0; z < nzeilen; z++) {
                            var zelle = tz[z].getElementsByTagName
 ("td"); // cells;
                            arr[z] = new Array(nspalten + 1);
                            arr[z][nspalten] = tz[z];
                            for (var s = 0; s < nspalten; s++) {
                                    var zi = getData(zelle[s], s);
                                    arr[z][s] = zi;
                                    // zelle[s].innerHTML 
  += "<br>"+zi+"<br>"+sorttype[s]; // zum Debuggen
                            }
                    }
            } // tableSort
    var initTableSort = function () {
                    var sort_Table = document.querySelectorAll
 ("table.sortierbar");
                    for (var i = 0; i < sort_Table.length; i++) new 
 tableSort(sort_Table[i]);
            } // initTable
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
            initTableSort, false); // nicht im IE8

 })();
```

Another of the javaScript-files I tried:

```
  ( function() {

    "use strict";

    var JB_sortbutStyle = document.createElement('style'); // Stylesheet 
  fÃ¼r Button im TH
    JB_sortbutStyle.innerText = 'button.sortbut { width:100%; height:100%; 
  border: none; background-color: transparent; font: inherit; color: 
  inherit; text-align: inherit; padding: 0; cursor: pointer; } 
  button.sortbut::-moz-focus-inner { margin: -1px; border-width: 1px; 
  padding: 0; }';
    document.head.appendChild(JB_sortbutStyle);

            var JB_Table = function(tab) {

            var up = String.fromCharCode(9650);
            var down = String.fromCharCode(9660);
            // var up = String.fromCharCode(8593);
            // var down = String.fromCharCode(8595);
            // var up = String.fromCharCode(11014);
            // var down = String.fromCharCode(11015);
            var no = String.fromCharCode(160,160,160,160); // Idee: 9674 ???
            var dieses = this;
            var defsort = 0;
            var startsort_u = -1,startsort_d = -1;
            var first = true;
            var ssort;
            var tbdy = tab.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            var tz = tbdy.rows;
            var nzeilen = tz.length;
            if (nzeilen==0) return;
            var nspalten = tz[0].cells.length;
            var Titel = tab.getElementsByTagName("thead")
   [0].getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("th");
            var Arr = new Array(nzeilen);
            var ct = 0;
            var sdir = new Array(nspalten);
            var stype = new Array(nspalten);
            var sortable = new Array(nspalten);
            for(var i=0;i<nspalten;i++) {
                    stype[i] = "n";
                    sdir[i] = "u";
                    sortable[i] = false;
            }

            var initTableHead = function(t,nr) {
                    var b = document.createElement("button");
                    b.type = "button";
                    b.className = "sortbut"
                    b.innerHTML = t.innerHTML;
                    t.innerHTML = "";
                    if(window.addEventListener) b.addEventListener
  ("click",function() { dieses.sort(nr); },false);
                    b.title = 'Die Tabelle nach "'+b.textContent+'" 
  sortieren.';
                    t.appendChild(b);
                    sortsymbol.init(t,no);
                    if(t.className.indexOf("vorsortiert-")>-1) {
                            sortsymbol.set(t,down);
                            ssort = nr;
                    }
                    else if(t.className.indexOf("vorsortiert")>-1) {
                            sortsymbol.set(t,up);
                            ssort = nr;
                    }
                    if(t.className.indexOf("sortiere-")>-1) startsort_d=nr;
                    else if(t.className.indexOf("sortiere")>-1) 
   startsort_u=nr;
                    sortable[nr] = true;
            } // initTableHead

            var sortsymbol = {
                    init: function(t,s) {
                            var tt = t.querySelector("button");
                            var sp = tt.getElementsByTagName("span");
                            for(var i=0;i<sp.length;i++) {
                                    if(!sp[i].hasChildNodes()) {
                                            t.sym = sp[i].appendChild
   (document.createTextNode(s));
                                            break;
                                    }
                            }
                            if(typeof(t.sym)=="undefined") t.sym = 
   tt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
                    },
                    set: function(t,s) {
                            t.sym.data = s;
                    },
                    get: function(t) {
                            return t.sym.data;
                    }
            } // sortsymbol

            var VglFkt_s = function(a,b) {
                    var as = a[ssort], bs = b[ssort];
                    var ret=(as>bs)?1:(as<bs)?-1:0;
                    if(!ret && ssort!=defsort) {
                            if (stype[defsort]=="s") { as = a[defsort]; bs 
   = b[defsort]; ret = (as>bs)?1:(as<bs)?-1:0; }
                            else ret = parseFloat(a[defsort])-parseFloat(b
   [defsort])
                    }
                    return ret;
            } // VglFkt_s

            var VglFkt_n = function(a,b) {
                    var ret = parseFloat(a[ssort])-parseFloat(b[ssort]);
                    if(!ret && ssort!=defsort) {
                            if (stype[defsort]=="s") { var as = a
   [defsort],bs = b[defsort]; ret = (as>bs)?1:(as<bs)?-1:0; }
                            else ret = parseFloat(a[defsort])-parseFloat(b
   [defsort]);
                    }
                    return ret;
            } // VglFkt_n

            var convert = function(val,s) {
                    var dmy;
                    var trmdat = function() {
                            if(dmy[0]<10) dmy[0] = "0" + dmy[0];
                            if(dmy[1]<10) dmy[1] = "0" + dmy[1];
                            if(dmy[2]<10) dmy[2] = "200" + dmy[2];
                            else if(dmy[2]<20) dmy[2] = "20" + dmy[2];
                            else if(dmy[2]<99) dmy[2] = "19" + dmy[2];
                            else if(dmy[2]>9999) dmy[2] = "9999";
                    }
                    if(val.length==0) val = "0";
                    if(!isNaN(val) && val.search(/[0-9]/)!=-1) return val;
                    var n = val.replace(",",".");
                    if(!isNaN(n) && n.search(/[0-9]/)!=-1) return n;
                    n = n.replace(/\s|&nbsp;|&#160;|\u00A0/g,"");
                    if(!isNaN(n) && n.search(/[0-9]/)!=-1) return n;
                    if(!val.search
    (/^\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s+\d+:\d\d\:\d\d\s*$/)) {
                            var dp = val.search(":");
                            dmy = val.substring(0,dp-2).split(".");
                            dmy[3] = val.substring(dp-2,dp);
                            dmy[4] = val.substring(dp+1,dp+3);
                            dmy[5] = val.substring(dp+4,dp+6);
                            for(var i=0;i<6;i++) dmy[i] = parseInt(dmy
   [i],10);
                            trmdat();
                            for(var i=3;i<6;i++) if(dmy[i]<10) dmy[i] = "0" 
   + dmy[i];
                            return (""+dmy[2]+dmy[1]+dmy[0]+"."+dmy[3]+dmy
    [4]+dmy[5]).replace(/ /g,"");
                    }
                    if(!val.search
   (/^\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s+\d+:\d\d\s*$/)) {
                            var dp = val.search(":");
                            dmy = val.substring(0,dp-2).split(".");
                            dmy[3] = val.substring(dp-2,dp);
                            dmy[4] = val.substring(dp+1,dp+3);
                            for(var i=0;i<5;i++) dmy[i] = parseInt(dmy
   [i],10);
                            trmdat();
                            for(var i=3;i<5;i++) if(dmy[i]<10) dmy[i] 
   = "0"+dmy[i];
                            return (""+dmy[2]+dmy[1]+dmy[0]+"."+dmy[3]+dmy
   [4]).replace(/ /g,"");
                    }
                    if(!val.search(/^\s*\d+:\d\d\:\d\d\s*$/)) {
                            dmy = val.split(":");
                            for(var i=0;i<3;i++) dmy[i] = parseInt(dmy
   [i],10);
                            for(var i=0;i<3;i++) if(dmy[i]<10) dmy[i] 
   = "0"+dmy[i];
                            return (""+dmy[0]+dmy[1]+"."+dmy[2]).replace
    (/ /g,"");
                    }
                    if(!val.search(/^\s*\d+:\d\d\s*$/)) {
                            dmy = val.split(":");
                            for(var i=0;i<2;i++) dmy[i] = parseInt(dmy
   [i],10);
                            for(var i=0;i<2;i++) if(dmy[i]<10) dmy[i] 
   = "0"+dmy[i];
                            return (""+dmy[0]+dmy[1]).replace(/ /g,"");
                    }
                    if(!val.search(/^\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+\s*\.\s*\d+/)) {
                            dmy = val.split(".");
                            for(var i=0;i<3;i++) dmy[i] = parseInt(dmy
   [i],10);
                            trmdat();
                            return (""+dmy[2]+dmy[1]+dmy[0]).replace
   (/ /g,"");
                    }
                    stype[s] = "s";

   //                        return val.toLowerCase().replace(/ 
   \u00e4/g,"ae").replace(/\u00f6/g,"oe").replace(/\u00fc/g,"ue").replace(/
   \u00df/g,"ss");
                    return val.toLowerCase().replace(/\u00e4/g,"a ").replace
   (/\u00f6/g,"o ").replace(/\u00fc/g,"u ").replace(/\u00df/g,"ss");
            } // convert

            this.sort = function(sp) {
                    if(sp<0 || sp>=nspalten) return;
                    if(!sortable[sp]) return;
                    if (first) {
                            for(var z=0;z<nzeilen;z++) {
                                    var zelle = tz[z].getElementsByTagName
   ("td"); // cells;
                                    Arr[z] = new Array(nspalten+1);
                                    Arr[z][nspalten] = tz[z];
                                    for(var s=0;s<nspalten;s++) {
                                            if (zelle[s].getAttribute("data-
   sort_key"))
                                                    var zi = convert(zelle
   [s].getAttribute("data-sort_key"),s);
                                            else if (zelle[s].getAttribute
   ("sort_key"))
                                                    var zi = convert(zelle
   [s].getAttribute("sort_key"),s);
                                            else
                                                    var zi = convert(zelle
   [s].textContent,s);
                                            Arr[z][s] = zi ;
                                            // zelle[s].innerHTML 
   += "<br>"+zi; // zum Debuggen
                                    }
                            }
                            first = false;
                    }
                    if(sp==ssort) {
                            Arr.reverse() ;
                            if ( sortsymbol.get(Titel[ssort])==down )
                                    sortsymbol.set(Titel[ssort],up);
                            else
                                    sortsymbol.set(Titel[ssort],down);
                    }
                    else {
                            if ( ssort>=0 && ssort<nspalten ) sortsymbol.set
   (Titel[ssort],no);
                                    ssort = sp;
                            if(stype[ssort]=="s") Arr.sort(VglFkt_s);
                            else                  Arr.sort(VglFkt_n);
                            if(sdir[ssort]=="u") {
                                    sortsymbol.set(Titel[ssort],up);
                            }
                            else {
                                    Arr.reverse() ;
                                    sortsymbol.set(Titel[ssort],down);
                            }
                    }
                    for(var z=0;z<nzeilen;z++)
                            tbdy.appendChild(Arr[z][nspalten]);
                    if(typeof(JB_aftersort)=="function") JB_aftersort
    (tab,tbdy,tz,nzeilen,nspalten,ssort);
            } // sort

            if(!tab.title.length) tab.title="Ein Klick auf die 
    Spalten\u00fcberschrift sortiert die Tabelle.";
            for(var i=Titel.length-1;i>-1;i--) {
                    var t=Titel[i];
                    if(t.className.indexOf("sortier")>-1) {
                            ct++;
                            initTableHead(t,i);
                            defsort = i ;
                            if(t.className.indexOf("sortierbar-")>-1) sdir
   [i] = "d";
                    }
    }
            if(ct==0) {
                    for(var i=0;i<Titel.length;i++)
                            initTableHead(Titel[i],i);
                    defsort = 0;
            }
            if(startsort_u>=0) this.sort(startsort_u);
            if(startsort_d>=0) { this.sort(startsort_d); this.sort
   (startsort_d); }
            if(typeof(JB_aftersortinit)=="function") JB_aftersortinit
   (tab,tbdy,tz,nzeilen,nspalten,-1);

    } // JB_Table

    var JB_initTableSort = function() {
            if (!document.querySelectorAll) return;
            var JB_Tables = [];
            var Sort_Table = document.querySelectorAll("table.sortierbar, 
   table[sortable]");
            for(var i=0;i<Sort_Table.length;i++) JB_Tables.push(new JB_Table
   (Sort_Table[i]));

            var pars = decodeURI(window.location.search.substring(1));
            if(pars.length) { // jbts=((0,1),(10,0),(3,3),(2,2))   tnr,snr
                    pars = pars.replace(/\s/g,"");
                    pars = pars.match(/jbts=\(?(\(\d+,\d+\),?){1,}\)?/gi);
                    if(pars) {
                            pars = pars[0].substr(pars[0].search("=")+1);
                            pars = pars.replace(/\(\(/g,"(").replace(/\)
   \)/g,")").replace(/\)\(/g,")|(").replace(/\),\(/g,")|(");
                            pars = pars.split("|");
                            for(var i=0;i<pars.length;i++) {
                                    var p = pars[i].substring(1,pars
   [i].length-1).split(",");
                                    if(p[0]>-1&&p[0]<JB_Tables.length) 
   JB_Tables[p[0]].sort(p[1]);
                            }
                    }
            }
    } // initTableSort

    if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener
   ("DOMContentLoaded",JB_initTableSort,false);

   })();
```

I would be more than happy if anybody could help me with this Problem!

Answer (score 0):

How about sorting the table before displaying?

For example, if your link to the page is:

```
http://example.com/view/product_table
```

The code for querying the table is:

```
function getTable($order = null) {
    $statement = "SELECT * FROM product_table";
    if ($order) {
        // switch case to prevent sql injection
        switch ($order) {
            case: "price":
                $statement .= " ORDER BY product_price";
                break;
        }
    }
    // Continue the build sql here 
}
```

Have the sorting button redirect to:

```
http://example.com/view/product_table?sort=price
```

Call function by:

```
getTable($GET[sort]);
```

To further my answer

1. I would suggest separating the code responsible for displaying and the code for building data
2. Name your variable to something more meaningful

Currently your code is very hard to maintain and read.

Comment: I have already tried the solution suggested by 
 
Stefan Michelangelo Mihajlovic and it works well with normal tables. However, not with my dynamic table generated from SQL-data. Do I have any error in my code that escaped my attention?

Comment: My solution should works with your table since they only affect sql side. The table is sorted BEFORE it was passed into your code. As for error in your code, it is impossible for me to comment because your code is only readable by you. To be honest, I won't be surprise that you will not be able to understand your code after a month or two.

Answer (score 0):

I used tablesorter for same purpose. I created table dynamically from database and it worked. First add to table id="myTable". After just call the script by adding code below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#myTable").tablesorter();
}
);
```

Note: Don't forget to include src="jquery.tablesorter.js" (download it from [download link](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Download)).

Now you should be able to sort your table by all columns by just clicking on table header of column.

EDIT:

Insted of:

```
echo "<table id=myTable class=tablesorter>";
```

Put:

```
echo "<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>";
```

Comment: I have already tried the solution suggested by Stefan Michelangelo Mihajlovic and it works well with normal tables. However, not with my dynamic table generated from SQL-data. Do I have any error in my code that escaped my attention?

Comment: @Columbus This should work with static and dynamic tables, function is called after page is loaded so table is already created when page is loaded. If your table is succesfully created  try putting 
echo  "<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>" instead of all in
echo "<table id=myTable class=tablesorter>";
Note: check in viewsorce if your table has correct id and class

Comment: @Columbus Also make sure you correctly added <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> in head section
And that u have jquery.tablesorter.js file  downloaded and putted in project folder js/

Comment: Thanks for your Input! I made the suggested changes. The table is created correctly, but in contrast to static tables, the columns are not sortable yet.

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> is added correctly because another static table in the same folder works well.

Comment: @Columbus well if table has id='myTable' and class='tablesorter' 
i cant think why its not working except if you didnt corretly include jquery.tablesorter.js 
Also to sort table you need to click on <th> cell. You can download examples from the link i wrote in answer and check once again if u missed smt. Goodluck

Comment: I found the error: echo "</tbody>"; was in the while-loop and has to be outside, now it´s working!! Thank you for your help!! :)

Comment: @Columbus No problem, if you can, vote up or accept the answer ^^